# Первый вызов скрипта без данных

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа, setinterval

Прошу помочь исправить: первый раз выводится пустое окно, следующие - уже заполненные.
Код

```
<div class="b-popup" id="popup1">
<div class="b-popup-content">
    <div class="inst-logo"><img class="inst-logo-img" src="http://www.kkk.com<?php echo $omg->templateUrl.'/images/logoblock.png'; ?>"></div>
    <div class="inst-body">
        <span id="popupname"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Скрипт

```
var quotes = new Array();
quotes[0] = "test1";
quotes[1] = "test2";

function showquote() {
var q = quotes.length;
var whichquote = Math.round(Math.random() * (q - 1));
document.getElementById('popupname').innerHTML = quotes[whichquote]
}

function PopUpShow() {
setTimeout(showquote, 3000);
document.getElementById('popup1').style.display = 'block';
setTimeout("document.getElementById('popup1' ).style.display = 'none'", 3000);
}

setInterval(PopUpShow, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем коде функция `showquote` первый раз вызывается через 8 секунд после загрузки страницы.

```
showquote();
setInterval(PopUpShow, 5000);
```

P.S. Попробуйте объяснить словами - себе и нам - логику того, что Вы (или Ваш код) делаете. Функция `showquote` и код, который прячет `'popup1'` будут вызваны практически одновременно.

P.P.S.

Используйте

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('popup1' ).style.display = 'none'; }, 3000);
```

вместо строки первым параметром `setTimeout`.